# Sequelize 3 tables with where between the 2 joined tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to replicate this MySQL query in Sequelize:

```
select u.email, a.serverId, ak.apikey from users u
join accounts a on u.id = a.userId
join apikeys ak on ak.userId = u.id
where u.state = "active" and ak.state = 1 and a.serverId = ak.serverId
```

This is my translation, except for the final `and` clause (`a.serverId = ak.serverId`) which I'm not sure how to achieve:

```
const activeKeys = await models.User.findAll({
        attributes: ['email'],
        raw: true,
        where: {
            state: "active"
        },
        include: [{
            model: models.Account,
            attributes: ['serverId']
        },
        {
            model: models.Apikey,
            attributes: ['apikey'],
            where: {
                state: 1
            }
        }]
    })
```

I've tried multiple combinations of associations, these are the current ones:

```
db.Account.belongsTo(db.User) // account has 1 user
db.User.hasMany(db.Account) // user has multiple accounts
db.User.hasMany(db.Apikey) // user has multiple apikeys
db.Apikey.belongsTo(db.User) // apikey has 1 user
db.Apikey.hasMany(db.Account) // apikey has many accounts
db.Account.hasOne(db.Apikey) // account has 1 apikey
```

The only part that is missing is the `and` clause between the 2 included models. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the main `where`:

```js
where: Sequelize.and(
  Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("state"), "=", "active"),
  Sequilize.where(Sequelize.col("Account.serverId"),"=", Sequelize.col("Apikey.serverId"))
)
```

Comment: Thanks Anatoly, I added it to the main `where` (the user where) but I then get: `SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Account.exchangeId' in 'where clause'` - seems it isn't recognising the included models while in the main `where`?

Comment: Try to include this column in `attributes` option of included model